# Computing the Sum of Values in a Column

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, sum

I am trying to write a python program that computes the sum of values from csv data file.  The csv file simply contains three columns and three rows containing numeric data.  The csv data file looks like the following:

```
Colum1,Colum2,Colum3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

I am having problem with my python code to compute the sum.  Somehow it is not computing the sum of all the values of Colum1, rather it just prints the two rows/values of 'Colum1'

```
import csv
file = open('data.csv')
rows = csv.DictReader(file)
for r in rows:
    print sum([float(r['Colum1'])])
```

Any thought how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sum over all rows and not just one:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    print sum(float(r['Colum1']) for r in rows)
```

Also, it is a good practice to close opened files, the `with .. as ..` syntax takes care of this

Comment: I am still not getting why the syntax:
`for r in rows:
print sum(float(r['Colum1']))` does not work! Could you explain how your code is different?

Thanks :)

Comment: @MEhsan you were applying `sum()` to each value separately, the sum of a single value is obviously the value itself. My code applies `sum()` once on all values under `Colum1` and gives you the output you wanted

Comment: Would the syntax be giving different results if we did not use comprehensions?  I mean having the for loop `for r in rows` outside sum() gives the faulty result?

Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @MEhsan yes, if you want the loop on the outaide then you need to maintain your own accumulator variable and add each value to it. The sum function doesn't carry information from one iteration of the loop to the other, it has to be given all values to sum in a single application.